# How to show actual image size on tableviewcell without using custom cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am showing image on cell using  `cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"demoImg.png"];` but in this image is not showing as its actual size.

Is there any way to show image in actual size?
[image]

Like this image is showing small but actual images are of different size and bigger but only if i click on cell it shows actual size

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }


    if (self.content.count > 0){

        NSDictionary *contentdata = self.content[indexPath.row];

        NSString *title = contentdata[@"description"];
        NSString *imageUrlString = contentdata[@"imageHref"];
       // NSString *description = contentdata[@"title"];

        cell.textLabel.text =  [title isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] ? @"" : title;  //----- Title
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"demoImg.png"];
       //cell.detailTextLabel.text  =  [description isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] ? @"" : description;  //----- Description

        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. THe default cell with image is designed to display icons.

Comment: You have to set your cell hight and width according to your orignal image .

Comment: Even if i set height bigger its not reflect on image...only if i click on cell it goes bigger

Comment: on default cell its not possible you have to take custom cell I think

Comment: @sss set constrain of your imageview top left bottom and right side and set imageview scale to aspectfill

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya imageview is not custom

Comment: @sss - can you show your code

Comment: You can try from here and be careful for constraints : https://github.com/pradeepkas/ResizingCellWithImageAndText

Comment: CANNOT BE DONE. YOU MUST CUSTOM CELL IT. END OF STORY.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this with the default cell, you need a custom cell. Then you can set it up how you like.